# javascript - replace multiple texts at once

Tags: javascript

I am looking for an easy and fast way to replace multiple strings in javascript.

My current approach looks something like this:

```
string.replace(string.replace(searchValue, newValue),newValue)
```

If I have to replace 10 strings in a text then this will be very big. Is there any other approach that can be used for replacing text in javascript?

Comment: Everytime the old value and new value will be different?

Comment: `My current approach` That looks quite odd - are you sure you don't mean `(string.replace(searchValue1, newValue1)).replace(searchValue2, newValue2)...` ?

Comment: using Regular Expressions is another approach. It's quite good at replacing multiple instances of a value with another value.

Comment: Are you replacing the same string over and over or are you replacing different strings each time? Do you have different replacement values or the same one over and over?

Comment: `.replace` _returns_ the replaced string. That’s why you can chain `.replace` calls together: `string.replace(oldValue1, newValue1).replace(oldValue2, newValue2)`.

Comment: I think what the problem OP facing is `string.replace` only replace the first occurrence of the searchValue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace and use a regex for the same
    test.replace(/hello/g, "liberty");
Working example :

```js
var test = "hello world , mine is hello and i will replace all hello with liberty"
var newStr = test.replace(/hello/g, "liberty");
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: This doesn’t really answer how to replace _multiple texts at once_.

Comment: He wanted to replace multiple strings, does he refer to all strings to be replaced being different and the replacing string to be different ?

Answer (score 1):

`split`, `map` and `replace` should work for you:

```js
const replaceString = (str, searchValue, newValue) => {
 let replaceStr = str.split(" ").map(value => {
      return value.replace(searchValue, newValue);
  });
  console.log(replaceStr.join(" ")); // Just for demo purpose, I am outputting the result to the console
};

const string = 'Hello world! How are you dear world?';
replaceString(string, 'world', 'earth');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str= "I am a am man";

function replaceString(fullString, searchValue, replaceValue) {
  while(!!~fullString.indexOf(searchValue)){
    fullString = fullString.replace(searchValue, replaceValue)
  }
  return fullString;
}
console.log(replaceString(str, 'am', 'x'))
```

You can use a simple while loop, and using `indexOf` to check existence, and replace until we can't find the text anymore