# JavaScript replace method for multiple/different searchValues and newValues

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

The closest I've found to talking about what I wanna do is [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51151728/javascript-replace-multiple-texts-at-once).

JavaScript has a very nice [replace method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp): `string.replace(searchValue, newValue)`

If I have a string like this:
`var str = '/by-the-pound/c/252'` and I want to replace the '/' with empty strings (essentially removing it), I can do something like this: `str.replace(/[/]/g, "");`

and if I want to replace 'c' with '-', I can do this: `str.replace(/c/g, "-");`

I understand that we can chain this like so: `str.replace(/[/]/g, "").replace(/c/g, "-");` and it will give us this: 'by-the-pound-252'

But what if I had a very long string, and wanted to replace, say 10 different characters, with 10 different values? That would be a very long, chained-up line of code with 10 `.replace` methods.

**TL;DR**

Is there a way to use one `.replace` but have multiple `searchValue's` and `newValue's`.

I've tried something like this (and many more), but nothing has worked:

```
str.replace(/[/]|[c]/g, ""|"-")
str.replace(/[/]|[c]/g, "","-");
str.replace(/[/],[c]/g, "","-");
str.replace(/[/|c]/g, [""|"-"]);
str.replace(/[/|c]/g, "","-");
```

**Why do I want to do this?** For brevity, for clean/easy-to-read code, etc...

Thank you for your time.

UPDATE:
The answer to my question is probably, No. There probably isn't a way to do what I asked, which was: Is there a way to use one .replace but have multiple searchValue's and newValue's? I looked through whatever docs I could find but didn't see any working examples of that. I realize that there are different ways of accomplishing what I want to do. I was able to create a function, for example, using an array of pairs like @DaveNewton suggested (similar to what both @MauroAguilar and @Ryan have done), and this worked fine, but I just wanted to know if you could do this in one simple line. Probably a wasted post. Mods feel free to remove. Thank you to all for taking the time.

Comment: Random syntactical attempts are likely not the most efficient approach :) The easiest would probably be an array of pairs, the char to replace, and its replacement. There are also libraries that include forms of string translations that work roughly the same way.

Comment: Is the requirement for single characters replacement or substrings too? I am asking because the solution can be very different for such cases.

Comment: @syduki for my immediate case, single chars only, but that's a good point about the substrings (I didn't think about that)

Comment: @DaveNewton random syntactical attempts was all i had left in my pea-brain :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with chaining but if what you want is some kind of utility that automates this process for you then you could write a simple utility function like this:

```
const replacer = (str, values) => 
    values.reduce((fstr, [val, rep]) => 
        fstr.replace(val, rep), str);
```

```js
const replacer = (str, values) => 
    values.reduce((fstr, [val, rep]) => 
        fstr.replace(val, rep), str);

const str = 'Peter Piper Picked a Peck of pickled peppers';

const result = replacer(str, [
  [/p/ig, 'B'],
  [/\s/g, '-'],
  [/-/g, '/']
]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Good job dude !

Answer (score 0):

I would make a list of replacements that can be added to and looped over.

```
export interface StringReplacement {
    find: string;
    replace: string;
}
```

Create a list of StringReplacement

```
const stringReplacements: StringReplacement[] = [
    {
        find: 'val1',
        replace: 'val2'
    },
    {
        find: 'val5',
        replace: 'val6'
    }
]
```

Then whenever you are ready to transform

```
const inputString = 'this val1 is the val5 input string.';

stringReplacements.forEach(replacement => 
    inputString = inputString.replace(replacement.find, replacement.replace)
);
```